# Kendo tabstrip and partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have kendo grid and inside a kendo tabstrip for showing some details, however this details are complex so I did a partial view and use the LoadContenFrom option of the tabstrip . This method ( LoadContenFrom  ) is never working and the method in my controller is never called. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is my example and it is working.

```
`$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
            animation: { open: { effects: "fadeIn"} },
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataContentField: "content",
            dataSource: [
                        {
                            text: "Tabb",
                            content: "This is tab one"
                        }]

        });
        var kTabs = $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
        kTabs.append({ text: "Test", contentUrl: "@Url.Content("~/Home/TestTabContent")" });
    });`
```

Hope this helps :)